# In Tomcat, is it possible to inject the current Host configuration without being inside a request context?

Tags: java, tomcat, dependency-injection, inject

We have a need to determine the server's URL. I know one can use JEE Dependency Injection for resources into servlets like this:

```
@Resource
private UserDatabase userDatabase;
```

I was curious if it possible to inject Host configuration, or something similar where I can figure out the entire local URL for the server.

I'm aware I can examine httpServletRequest, but I need to do this on boot of the container, so I would be outside the scope of a request and unable to use that api.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Note: The virtual host name (outside of a request) is not guaranteed to be unique. The server can answer to any number of host names, and the client-visible hostname might even be that of a proxy, not of your tomcat

Comment: yes, I'm aware of that and thank you for pointing that out. That's why I was curious if I could inject one or more of the host or context configurations